# Counting records from datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am using python with Django to develop application on google app engine.

Now my entity in data store contain millions or billions of record and I want to count those records in real time.

By using count() it takes more time then what I can afford

I want to count those record with in 2 or 3 second..

So can any one tell me what I should have to use to improve performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store the count in another entity (named Statistics for example), and modify your application so that the stored count is updated each time a new entity is inserted or deleted.

Comment: but that wont work in case of search query bocz I want also to count the records fetched in query and those records are in no of millions so for that it wont work.

Comment: @mahesh It's simply not possible to count millions of records as fast as you want - physical constraints make it impractical. This is why search engines such as Google return estimates of the number of actual results.